# populate dropdown with json (SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON..)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, fetch

I am trying to simply populate a dropdown with the `styleName` field values from my JSON data file.

My json data looks like this, for intance:

```
{"name":{"styleName":"name","fillType":"none","fillTrans":"0","outlineType":"solid","outlineWidth":"1","outlineColor":"#ff0000"}}  
{"sarah":{"styleName":"sarah","fillTrans":"none","fillTrans":"0","outlineType":"solid","outlineWidth":"1","outlineColor":"#ff0000"}}
//....
```

Below is my JS.

---

```
let dropdown = document.getElementById('tem');

dropdown.length = 0;

let defaultOption = document.createElement('option');
defaultOption.text = 'Choose Template';

dropdown.add(defaultOption);
dropdown.selectedIndex = 0;

const urld = '../../templates.json';

fetch(urld)  
  .then(  
    function(response) {  
      if (response.status !== 200) {  
        console.warn('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + 
          response.status);  
        return;  
      }

      // Examine the text in the response
      response.json().then(function(data) {  
        let option;
        console.log(data);
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          option = document.createElement('option');
          option.text = data[i].styleName;
          //option.value = data[i].abbreviation;
          dropdown.add(option);
        }    
      });  
    }  
  )  
  .catch(function(err) {  
    console.error('Fetch Error -', err);  
  });
```

---

I am constantly getting this error, despite a response `200`, dropdown remains blank..
**Error:**

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position xxx
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ VM8493:22
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ VM8493:13
```

Drop-down markup is simply this:

```
                    <select id="tem" class='w150'>
                    </select>
```

Comment: What is the *real* JSON data (text) at point of failure? Use browser's network tools to inspect the actual server response.

Comment: That JSON snippet is invalid. Take the _actual_ data over to https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I would expect [ row, row ], you are missing comma between rows in case it is single JSON and at least array brackets around. Also error should tell you exact char where your problem is. Or you can adjust a library if error message is too short for example. But I would start by console.log(response) and then use JSON.parse(response) in some local code to see problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 replace this option.text = data[i].styleName;
let keys=Object.keys(data[i])
    with option.text = data[i][keys[0]].styleName
```

Comment: Thanks, it is kind of hard to read.. You want me to just add this line, correct? 'option.text = data[i][keys[0]].styleName;'